# what does " error: conversion from 'double' to 'std::size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') is not allowed in a converted constant expression" mean?

Tags: c++

```
#define Tag std::bitset<32-8-log2(4*_N)>
#define Offset std::bitset<log2(4*_N)>
```

I tried to write a code in cpp with the following #define functions and i ended up with the error.

```
error: conversion from 'double' to 'std::size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') is not allowed in a converted constant expression
Tag* _tagBits;
```

Comment: Hint: Look up the return type of [`log2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/log2)

Comment: Try not to use `#define` in C++, ever. Use proper (`const` or `constexpr`) *variables* or functions. Macros are a *hack* and will make your life miserable in the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own `constexpr` (naive) log2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

constexpr std::size_t log2(std::size_t N)
{
    return N <= 1 ? 0 : 1+log2(N/2);
}

int main()
{
    std::bitset<1+log2(13)> b;
    std::cout << b << '\n'; // 0000
}
```